# Assertions in Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, assertion

I know I can filter a stream to get only those elements that are not null, and then do with them whatever I need. Something like this:

```
myList.stream().filter(element -> element != null).doOtherThings...
```

Is there a way to assert that the elements are not null in a stream function, so that it goes through all elements and if it finds one being null, it throws an exception? I've been thinking of something like the following:

```
myList.stream().assert(Objects::nonNull).doOtherThings...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some very good suggestions already. Allow me to supplement. If what you are after is an assertion as in an `assert` statement, I would like to make this explicit in the code in order to guide the reader about my purpose. To assert that your original list doesn’t contain any `null`s:

```
    assert ! myList.contains(null);
```

If the assertion is to be checked somewhere down the stream pipeline, the simple way is:

```
    assert myList.stream().map(this::transform).allMatch(Objects::nonNull);
```

If you don’t want to create a separate stream for the assertion but prefer to assert in the middle of your existing stream pipeline, use for example:

```
        myList.stream()
                .peek(e -> { assert e != null; })
                .toArray();
```

You may worry that the use of `peek` is not so nice, which is also why I mention this option last. `peek` is documented to exist “mainly to support debugging” (quote taken out of its context), so you may say that it’s related to the purpose of `assert` and thus defend its use in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Use something like

```
.map(Objects::requireNonNull)
```

You just need to apply an operation which will throw an exception, but otherwise passes the argument through.

Although, unless there is a good reason not to iterate the list multiple times, it might be clearer to separate the checking and the processing:

```
if (myList.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)) {
  throw ...
}
// Do things with list.
```

Comment: Note however that these two approaches proposed here are not equivalent - the second (separate) one checks if any element in the entire list is null, while the first one (the mapping step) only checks elements which are actually processed, which may be only a subset or even none at all, depending on the terminal operation and the rest of the pipeline. You need to choose what makes most sense for your use-case.

Comment: Of course, you can also use the good old `if(myList.contains(null)) throw …` or `myList.forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);`

Answer (score 3):

To the map method I prefer to use peek method. I think it is more expressive then uing map method that has to return some value.

```
    list.stream()
            .peek(Objects::requireNonNull)
```

However what i think is hard to understand is that stream is not executed until the collect() is called. That is why doing this kind of conditional logic is hard using streams. To be honest if you want to achieve the desired effect you have to do something like this.

```
list.stream()
            .peek(Objects::requireNonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(t -> do whatever ... )
```